# Use airflow hive operator and output to a text file

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Hi I want to execute hive query using airflow hive operator and output the result to a file. I don't want to use INSERT OVERWRITE here.

```
hive_ex = HiveOperator(
    task_id='hive-ex',
    hql='/sql/hive-ex.sql',
    hiveconfs={
        'DAY': '{{ ds }}',
        'YESTERDAY': '{{ yesterday_ds }}',
        'OUTPUT': '{{ file_path }}'+'csv',
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

What is the best way to do this?

I know how to do this using bash operator,but want to know if we can use hive operator

```
hive_ex = BashOperator(
    task_id='hive-ex',
    bash_command='hive -f hive.sql -DAY={{ ds }} >> {{ file_path }} 
    /file_{{ds}}.json',
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: BashOperator will work to run hive?
we need to connect to HDFS and in HDFS we can hive - f <.hql>?

Answer (score 4):

Since it is a pretty custom use-case the best way is to extend the Hive operator (or create your own Hive2CSVOperator). The implementation would depend on whether you have access to hive through CLI or HiveServer2.

**Hive CLI**

I would try first with configuring the Hive CLI connection and adding the `hive_cli_params`, as per [Hive CLI hook code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/5127ea34e110891c56e1ba9f70211091d13fa553/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L9), and if this doesn't work, extend the Hook (which would give you access to everything).

**HiveServer2**

There is a separate hook for this case ([link](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/5127ea34e110891c56e1ba9f70211091d13fa553/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L753)). It is a bit more convenient because it has a `get_results` method ([source](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/5127ea34e110891c56e1ba9f70211091d13fa553/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L834)) or `to_csv` method ([source](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/5127ea34e110891c56e1ba9f70211091d13fa553/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L852)).

The `execute` in the operator code could look then similar to this:

```
def execute():
  ...
  self.hook = HiveServer2Hook(...)
  self.conn = self.hook.get_conn()

  self.conn.to_csv(hql=self.hql, csv_filepath=self.output_filepath, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

you need airflow hooks. see [Hooks](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#hooks) and [HiveHook](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.html), there's a `to_csv` method or you can use `get_records` method and then do it yourself.