# How can I export Hive Operator output into csv file locally using airflow?

Tags: hive, hiveql, airflow

I am trying to export the output of HiveOperator(Hive SQL ) into csv file and store it locally. Wondering how can I do it in airflow. Could anyone share your thoughts on this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322905/use-airflow-hive-operator-and-output-to-a-text-file

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Hive Operator that inherits the `HiveOperator` in your DAG similar to below:

```py
class CustomHiveOp(HiveOperator):
    def execute(context):
        self.log.info('Executing: %s', self.hql)
        self.hook = self.get_hook()

        self.conn.to_csv(
            hql=self.hql, 
            csv_filepath=self.output_filepath, 
            schema='default',
            delimiter=',',
            lineterminator='\r\n',
            output_header=True,
            fetch_size=1000,
            hive_conf=None)
```

and use it as:

```py
hive_csv = CustomHiveOp(
    task_id='hive_to_csv',
    hql='YOUR_HIVE_QUERY',
    hive_cli_conn_id=''
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find what you need if you use a `PythonOperator` or subclass `HiveOperator` using `HiveServer2Hook` in the `execute` method:

```
def execute(context):
  ...
  self.hook = HiveServer2Hook(...)
  self.conn = self.hook.get_conn()

  self.conn.to_csv(hql=self.hql, csv_filepath=self.output_filepath, ...)
```